# how validation works in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I was reading documentation of mongoose: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html

It is said that validation occurs before saving document in the database.

And to turn this feature off we have to set **option: validateBeforeSave** to **false**.

However I have another decent Node.js tutorial example where they just use .validate as follows:

```
      var course = new Course({});

      course.validate(function(err) {
        assert.ok(err);
        assert.equal(err.errors['title'].kind, 'required');

        course.title = 'Introduction to Computer Science';
        assert.equal(course.title, 'Introduction to Computer Science');

        var s = '0123456789';
        course.title = '';
        while (course.title.length < 150) {
          course.title += s;
        }

        course.validate(function(err) {
          assert.ok(err);
          assert.equal(err.errors['title'].kind, 'maxlength');

          ++succeeded;
          done();
        });
      });
```

I can't understand the underlying reason for using **validate** without setting **validateBeforeSave** option to **false**? Could someone please clarify how the provided code above works?

Answer (score 0):

`validateBeforeSave`, as the name implies, validates the mongoose object before persisting it to database. This is a schema level check, which, if not set to false, will validate every document. It includes both built-in (like a Number cannot contain string or a required field should exist etc.) and custom defined validations.

`validate` does the same, only it has no concern with saving the document afterwards. It's the method on the object which you invoke, like `course.validate(callback)`, and get to know if the object is valid or not through err in the callback.

Both are doing one and the same thing but at different times and different level. Also, both are not mutually exclusive, so one does not need to be set off for other to work.

As for the use case of `validate`, unit testing is one example. You may want to test your validators without the trouble of mocking `save` or setting up a test database. I believe the example is trying to do something like that, though not in a structured way.

Answer (score 0):

As you said mongoose is fireing up validation before save operation, but there are some cases when you want to validate document schema without save. For this you can use validate method directly. 
Your example from tutorial show us piece of code representing unit tests. So for example we can check methods which generate some model to save without saving him. 
Also validate method could help when you have complicated action flow with many saves and dependencies. For example you want to save user dashboard model with proper structure but firstly you saving user profile. With validate method and for instance wrong dashboard structure you can check request and throw exception before saving user profile.

Answer (score 0):

In the example code, they are using **Async Custom Validator** which you would understand better if you check this: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#built-in-validators

They are used when standard validation is not enough and this is purely my observation that they are usually used in testing along with some testing framework and assetion library.

Comment: Thank you, it is easy to get lost in the documentation

Comment: The **Async Custom Validator** part is plainly wrong and misleading. The code is not even using custom validator let alone async one. The two validations tested are `required` and `minLength` which are mongoose built-in and definitely not async.

Comment: @TalhaAwan please see the documentation and sample code provided there for yourself

Comment: In the documentation you shared, please see under **Built-in Validators** . You'll find `required` and `maxLength` validators. 1) These are not custom 2) These are not async. And these are the exact two validators tested in the above code.

Comment: You are right partially, but there are other validations as well, not just them, for instance to validate title, hereby it is custom validator. And if it wasn't async the author of the code would use .validateAsync() rather than .validate()